# When to Perform non-linear dimension reduction

Tags: machine-learning, r

When do we feel need to go through non-linear transformation like kernel PCA ? Please share an example

Comment: Welcome to Data Science! Please, make your questions more detailed and specific. You're asking people to devote their time to answer your questions. If you're expecting quality answers, please consider asking quality questions (try some googling, read something on the topic, and update your posts with detailed, self-researched content). We will be glad to help you.

Answer (score 3):

The question is too general to have a specific recipe as an answer. Depends on the data and the relation between features but to the best of my knowledge:

When the relation between your features are non-linear i.e. when a non-linear interpretation of correlation between features makes more sense than the linear interpretation.

A detailed explanation of what I mean can be found in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101344/is-kernel-pca-with-linear-kernel-equivalent-to-standard-pca) nice answer. Please note that the $X^TX$ in the 4th line of the first paragraph should be $XX^T$, because in data mining, we conventionally use $N\times D$ format for data matrices. So in this example, we are looking for the gram matrix of the rows and not columns.

Hope it helps :)